# Wordpress content template

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I it possible some way in wordpress how precreate a part of post and save it to later use and mass edit ?

For example on end of every post I insert my  special signature somethink like (I USE VISUAL COMPOSER ) :

[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column width="1/2"][vc_column_text]I am text block.[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][vc_column width="1/2"][vc_single_image image="50"][/vc_column][/vc_row]

How can I save this signature for easy insert to every post ? And in some case edit in just on one place.

Maybe some plugin ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can handle this process by using `save_post` action, `save_post` is an action triggered whenever a post or page is created or updated.
then you can update every new post and adding signature directly.

try add this code to `functions.php`

```
add_action('save_post','Add_Post_Signature');
function Add_Post_Signature($id){

    $Signature = 'I USE VISUAL COMPOSER !';

    $CreatedPost = get_post($id);

    $Updated_post = array(
        'ID'           => $id,
        'post_content' => $CreatedPost->post_content . '<br />' . $Signature,
    );

    wp_update_post( $Updated_post );
}
```